# Get members's avatarHash when getting cards from Trello

Tags: api, avatar, trello

According to the Trello API documentation, it is possible to return a member's avatarHash as part of the data for the cards on a list. I should be able to use the feed from either of the following:

- https://trello.com/1/lists/[LIST_ID]/cards?member_fields=all
- https://trello.com/1/lists/[LIST_ID]/cards?member_fields=avatarHash

However, for me anyway, the data is exactly the same with or without the query paramaters. I have also tried adding my application key and a token to the URL, but still no success.

What I actually want to do is get the URI for a member's avatar, and I believe I can build the correct one with the hash. Any help to do this or any pointers as to what I am doing wrong will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: this is kinda beta, you should expect glitches and maybe report them back to trello. Actually is "API Reference (Beta)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trello's documentation for their [API](https://trello.com/docs/api/card/index.html) shows that there are optional fields, but it isn't clear or even stated (although fairly obvious after reading) that for the `member_fields` parameter to be valid, there should also be `members=true` specified as part of the URI.

I came across this when inspecting the API calls Trello make themselves and having removed everything but `member_fields`, things even went missing for them, but adding `members` back in worked as expected.

Right now, my API call is finally working and looks like this:

- https://trello.com/1/lists/[LIST_ID]/cards?members=true&member_fields=avatarHash

Comment: you figure it out yourself :)

Comment: you must have commented while I was typing the answer out. It is indeed in Beta, so have sent a suggestion for the API docs.